# Meteor, How can I display a url query in the client?

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor, but it seems like this should be simple. I want to create a page that pulls a get variable down and displays it on the client

```
ex: www.example.com?yourname=bob
```

and the page would display

```
bob
```

I feel like this should be easy, but so far have not been able to do it. I created an call when the client loads that asks for the info, but it doesn't work on the first load for some reason. On subsequent loads it does.

```
<head>
  <title>Page Chat</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        {{> name}}
    </div>
</body>

<template name="name">
  {{name}}
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

js code

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function(){
    Meteor.call("getData", function(error, result){
        if(error){
          Session.set("name", "bob");
        }
        else{
          Session.set("name", result.name);
        }
    });

  });

  Template.name.name = function(){
    return Session.get("name");
  };
  Template.name.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var connect = Npm.require('connect');
  var app = __meteor_bootstrap__.app;
  var post, get;

  app
    // parse the POST data
    .use(connect.bodyParser())
    // parse the GET data
    .use(connect.query())
    // intercept data and send continue
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
      post = req.body;
      get = req.query;
      return next();
  });
  Meteor.startup(function () {
  });
  Meteor.methods({
    getData: function() {
      return get;
    },
    postData: function(){
      return post;
    }
  });
}
```

If possible I would like to share the data on the initial page load, it seems like a waste to create an separate page load to get information thats already there when the page is first loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be easier to use something like [meteor-router](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/router). Then you could do

server side js:

```
Meteor.Router.add('/something', function() {
  return this.params.yourname;
});
```

So if you visited `example.com/something?yourname=Bob` you would get back `Bob`.

Be careful when displaying something directly to the client from a querystring/input parameter as if you don't check it before it could be used for XSS.

Comment: Thanks, but since this is the only thing I need the url for, it seems silly to add a whole routing system. Maybe thats what I need to do, but it really seems like there should be some way to read the url from the client :(

Comment: It is on the roadmap https://trello.com/c/Lz07fBAm/7-page-model-server-side-rendering-rest-endpoints, in the meanwhile a package based router like meteor-router could do for you

Comment: +1, though Meteor Router is now deprecated in favor of [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router). If someone could add an example for Iron Router, that would be helpful.

Comment: This package is deprecated. Try below answer using Iron Router

Answer (score 0):

Original url is "http://example.com:3000/test?xyz", you can use any one below

Router.current().request.url
"http://example.com:3000/test?xyz"

Router.current().url
"http://example.com:3000/test?xyz"

Router.current().originalUrl
"http://example.com:3000/test?xyz"

Router.current().route._path
"/test"

Router.current().route.getName()
"test"

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/289